# pandas dataframe place rows with same column value together

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe,

```
   id name
0   1    a
1   2    b
2   3    c
3   4    b
4   5    a
```

I want to get the following result

Since the first row has name 'a', we would move all rows with name 'a' below the first row and pushing all other rows down.
Then we would do the same for all other `name`s (b, c..) maintaining the initial ordering of data

```
   id name
0   1    a
1   5    a
2   2    b
3   4    b
4   3    c
```

How can I do that with pandas dataframe?

I can think of iterating rows then remove the rows with the same name, and adding them below the current iterating row.
I'm wondering if there's a better way.
And I'm not sure if I can mutate dataframe as I iterate .

- edit

Maitaining the initial order .. in a sense that

you only move up a row if rows above it has the same `name` otherwise you don't change any ordering.
And ordering of the rows with the same `name` is the same as the initial ordering (relatively)

Comment: Use `df.sort_values(by='name')`?

Comment: `df.sort_values(by="name")`? Or what do you mean by maintaining the initial ordering of data? Edit: Wops, Zero beat me to it.

Comment: What if the first row contains `b` instead of `a`? Should we keep `b` the first row in the resulting df?

Comment: @soon yes, `b` would be the first row in that case.

Comment: @ialarmedalien i guess my question was not clear enough, I added more context, I wasn't successful at searching similar sorting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create key for each row in form of `(x, idx)` where `x` is the index of the name in the column `name_unique` which keeps the order of the original `name` column and contains distinct values only, and `idx` is the index in the original dataframe

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']})

In [27]: name_ord = {}

In [28]: ordering_list = []

In [29]: for idx, value in enumerate(df['name']):
    ...:     if value not in name_ord:
    ...:         name_ord[value] = len(name_ord)
    ...:     ordering_list.append((name_ord[value], idx))
    ...:

In [30]: df['ord'] = ordering_list

In [31]: df.sort_values(by='ord')
Out[31]:
   id name     ord
0   1    a  (0, 0)
4   5    a  (0, 4)
1   2    b  (1, 1)
3   4    b  (1, 3)
2   3    c  (2, 2)
```

Also keeps `b` on the top in the resulting dataframe if `b` was in the first row in the original dataframe:

```
In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'name': ['b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a']})

In [33]: name_ord = {}

In [34]: ordering_list = []

In [35]: for idx, value in enumerate(df['name']):
    ...:     if value not in name_ord:
    ...:         name_ord[value] = len(name_ord)
    ...:     ordering_list.append((name_ord[value], idx))
    ...:

In [36]: df['ord'] = ordering_list

In [37]: df.sort_values(by='ord')
Out[37]:
   id name     ord
0   1    b  (0, 0)
1   2    b  (0, 1)
2   3    c  (1, 2)
3   4    a  (2, 3)
4   5    a  (2, 4)
```

Comment: I see.. smart... !

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it. To get the order as it is, I used unique() function and then created another column having the order and then sorted it. The rest is to sort on `order` column and as you need the index to be in order as well, use the reset_index() method. This will add extra column index so to avoid that set the parameter drop to True.

```
    import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': [1,2,3,4,5],'name':['a','b','c','b','a']})
y = x['name'].unique().tolist()
#print(x)
order = []
for index,row in x.iterrows():
    order.append(y.index(row['name']))
x['order'] = order
x = x.sort_values(by=['order'])
x  = x.reset_index(drop=True)
print(x)
x = x.drop('order',axis=1)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
  id name  order
0   1    a      0
1   5    a      0
2   2    b      1
3   4    b      1
4   3    c      2
   id name
0   1    a
1   5    a
2   2    b
3   4    b
4   3    c
```

Comment: Does it work when first row contains `b` instead of `a`? The OP wants the resulting dataframe to contain `b` on the first row

Comment: @soon I edited the answer.. This works for `b` or any other element in the beginning.